# Ban enter to proceed with next question in Django survey

Tags: django, button, form-fields

I am writing a short survey in Django. The last question sould be a Feedback form field in which participants can enter their thoughts. However, if I press enter while filling in the feedback, they proceed to the next question. I want to ban the proceeding with enter (just in case they want to write a lot).

pages view:

```
class Feedback(Page):
    form_model = 'player'
    form_fields = ['feedback']
```

models view:

```
feedback = models.StringField(
        label='Is there any Feedback you would like to share?')
```

Comment: The problem is with moving cursor to next form field or with validating input on backend? Because it looks like a frontend issue.

Comment: There is no actual "problem" with the coding. The problem I have is that the probands automatically proceed with the next question when they press "enter". Do you know if there is any chance to prevent that? Like forcing them to click on the Next Button with the cursor?

Answer (score 1):

It's a front-end issue. You *might* address it in Django.

Simplest might be to use a `TextField` or a `TextInput` widget, which *ought* to accept Enter as just another character.

Alternatively you might add a BooleanField that defaults to False (rendered as unchecked checkbox) and which causes a validation error if it's not True when submitted.  So if the user submits before checking (f.ex.) "I agree for the above comment to be published" (or any other words that might be more appropriate), they get an error on that checkbox -- and can go back to typing their incomplete comment text. If they did not intend to submit using Enter, they will be grateful. If they did, they'll hopefully just sigh and check the little checkbox next to Submit.

Or make it a hidden input, defaulted to invalid, and use Jquery to set its value to valid, when the actual submit button is clicked. But that's back into front-end coding.